# When trying to call Apollo Client Query, I am always getting loading: true,networkStatus: true

Tags: reactjs, react-apollo, apollo-client

Query:

```
HOUSEDETAIL : gql`
query houseDetail($_id:ID){
 houseDetail(_id:$_id) {
   address
   address1
   street
   phoneNumber
   houseNo
 }
}
`,
```

Code in React  when Trying to call apolloClient  :

```
    const Page2 = compose(graphql(query.HOUSEDETAIL,{name:'houseDetail', options: (props) => ({variables: {_id:props.houseAddress._id,fetchPolicy: 'network-only'}})})) (Dashboard)
```

Error looks like this in the browser console:

```
        props{"houseAddress":{},"houseDetail":{"variables":{"fetchPolicy":"network-only"},"loading":true,"networkStatus":1}}
```

Comment: which version of `apollo-client` are you using? There was a bug apparently related to this https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/issues/1186

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a common issue and usualy solved by adding `notifyOnNetworkStatusChange: true`

In your specific scenario:

```
const Page2 = compose(
  graphql(
    query.HOUSEDETAIL,
    {
       name:'houseDetail', 
       options: (props) => ({
         variables: { 
           _id:props.houseAddress._id
         }, // ====> this bracket was also misplaced on your example code
         fetchPolicy: 'network-only',
         notifyOnNetworkStatusChange: true
       })
    }
  )
)(Dashboard)
```

More informatioin on `notifyOnNetworkStatusChange` can be found in ReactApollo [docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react-apollo.html#graphql-config-options-notifyOnNetworkStatusChange):